# Pushdown removes decimals at aggregator (sum) Informatica Powercenter

Tags: teradata, informatica-powercenter

I have a maping where I sum a few amounts using an aggregator, both in the source table and the target table the field is defined as decimal(15, 2). The tables are in Teradata. When I run the workflow without pushdown I get the correct amount, with decimals, say 16,11 for example. If I check the pushdown option (full pushdown) I find that the result inserted in the target table has lost the decimals (in our example 16.00). I am guessing that when the data arrives to the aggregator it still has the decimal part and that it loses it after the aggregator since if it had already lost the decimal part the result would be less than 16. I have taken a look at the sql form the pushdown and it doesn't seem to be casting anything to integer. I have also tried to cast the data in an expression and in the aggregator to force Teradata to to the correct cast, but I am getting the same result. 
Does anyone know what could be causing this?

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 0):

Full pushdown results in running SQL statements and no data processing by Informatica, so you need to review the queries in detail.

You might try checking the queries on some limited amount of data, some subset - to make the analysis easier.

Please check if `Allow Temporary View for Pushdown` session property has been enabled. If so, pay special attention to `PM_` views getting created. Review the definitions.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone runs into a similar issue, the problem was that a null was being passed to a union and that field was then interpreted as char.

Comment: The first Select of a Union determines the data types of the resulting columns and a NULL has an Integer datatype (not Char).